# How can I fix this configure error?

Tags: linux, compile, suse

I'm trying to build mosh from source on a SUSE10 machine and am getting the following error:

```
checking for protobuf... no
configure: error: Package requirements (protobuf) were not met:

No package 'protobuf' found

Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
installed software in a non-standard prefix.

Alternatively, you may set the environment variables protobuf_CFLAGS
and protobuf_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config.
See the pkg-config man page for more details.
```

I downloaded the source to protobuf and installed it in a custom path as well. I'm not using a package manager for any of this and cannot for various reasons outside the scope of the question. I added that custom path to my PATH and rehashed. Typically, this is enough for configure but in this case its not doing the trick. I added the prefix for protobuf to PKG_CONFIG_PATH but am still hitting this error.

What should I do next to get past this error?

Comment: Your PATH should not be relevant here. Does the configure script have a `--lib-prefix` option? How did you add the path to PKG_CONFIG_PATH?

Comment: Have you looked at `config.log` yet?

Comment: Didn't look at config.log but have now. There was a suggestion buried in there that helped. Needed to point it to lib/pkgconfig. Never know how to read those log files and still don't but got enough out of it. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

To fix this, run it like this:

```
export PREFIX=~/usr   
PKG_CONFIG_PATH=${PREFIX}/lib/pkgconfig; 
./configure --prefix=${PREFIX}
```

Comment: I needed to remove the semicolon

Answer (score 0):

You may need to install protobuf. Everything works fine after that .

https://github.com/google/protobuf

Comment: Welcome to Super User. The OP wrote "I downloaded the source to protobuf and installed it in a custom path as well". Your answer brings nothing new.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski People who are looking for answers skim the question. They may be confused by the name of two different packages: `protobuf` and `protobuf-c`. This answer will help.

Comment: @Han The question doesn't mention protobuf-c. Even the answer doesn't mention it, so I really do not understand your comment. I still think the answer advises what has already been done. If not, it should explain the difference: what went wrong in the first try and why the laconic (if not trivial) "install protobuf" should help in the next try. The link is a generic link to protobuf on GitHub, so it doesn't shed any light either.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski I faced same issue (actually same error text), google led me here and this answer helped. This error showed when I tried installing `protobuf-c`. I was so confused why there was such problem like that till I realized that they are 2 different packages. I upvoted the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else gets stuck on this, I found a solution here: https://narkive.com/kRRnccDo.2

> As part of installing protobuf, it should have installed a file called
> protobuf.pc, probably in /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/protobuf.pc. Assuming
> that's where it is, try:
>
> PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig ./configure

I initially tried just installing the binary from the protobuf github, but that didn't include the protobuf.pc file. I ended up having to build protobuf from source
and then executing
`PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig ./configure`

This is similar, but not quite the same as Roney's solution above